# In WPF, how can a Command's CanExecute method gain visibility of other UI elements?

Tags: c#, wpf, command

I've been using WPF for a while but I'm new to Commands, but would like to start using them properly for once. Following a code example, I've established a separate static Commands class to hold all of my commands, and it looks like this.

```
public static class Commands
{
    public static RoutedUICommand OpenDocument { get; set; }

    static Commands()
    {
        OpenDocument = new RoutedUICommand("Open Document", "OpenDocument", typeof(Commands));
    }

    public static void BindCommands(Window window)
    {
        window.CommandBindings.Add(new CommandBinding(OpenDocument, OpenDocument_Executed, OpenDocument_CanExecute));
    }

    private static void OpenDocument_CanExecute(object sender, CanExecuteRoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        // Should be set to true if an item is selected in the datagrid.
    }

    private static void OpenDocument_Executed(object sender, ExecutedRoutedEventArgs e)
    {

    }
}
```

My problem is that although the command is going to be bound to a Button control in MainWindow.xaml, the OpenDocument_CanExecute method needs to look at a DataGrid in MainWindow.xaml to see if an item is selected.

How can I wire things up such that the method can see the DataGrid?

**SOLUTION**

Inspired by Ken's reply (thanks again!), I put the following in place, which works perfectly.

**MainWindow.xaml.cs**

```
public partial class MainWindow
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        Loaded += delegate
        {
            DataContext = ViewModel.Current;
            Commands.BindCommands(this);
        };
    }
}
```

**ViewModel.cs**

```
public class ViewModel
{
    private static ViewModel _current;
    public static ViewModel Current
    {
        get { return _current ?? (_current = new ViewModel()); }
        set { _current = value; }
    }

    public object SelectedItem { get; set; }
}
```

**Commands.cs**

```
public static class Commands
{
    public static RoutedUICommand OpenDocument { get; set; }

    static Commands()
    {
        OpenDocument = new RoutedUICommand("Open Document", "OpenDocument", typeof(Commands));
    }

    public static void BindCommands(Window window)
    {
        window.CommandBindings.Add(new CommandBinding(OpenDocument, OpenDocument_Executed, OpenDocument_CanExecute));
    }

    private static void OpenDocument_CanExecute(object sender, CanExecuteRoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        e.CanExecute = ViewModel.Current.SelectedItem != null;
    }

    private static void OpenDocument_Executed(object sender, ExecutedRoutedEventArgs e)
    {

    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`ICommand` implementations work best in the **MVVM** pattern:

```
class ViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged {
    class OpenDocumentCommand : ICommand {
        public bool CanExecute(object parameter) {
            return ViewModel.ItemIsSelected;
        }
        public OpenDocumentCommand(ViewModel viewModel) {
            viewModel.PropertyChanged += (s, e) => {
                if ("ItemIsSelected" == e.PropertyName) {
                    RaiseCanExecuteChanged();
                }
            };
        }
    }

    private bool _ItemIsSelected;

    public bool ItemIsSelected {
        get { return _ItemIsSelected; }
        set {
            if (value == _ItemIsSelected) return;
            _ItemIsSelected = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged("ItemIsSelected");
        }
    }

    public ICommand OpenDocument { 
        get { return new OpenDocumentCommand(this); } 
    }
}
```

Obviously, I left out a whole bunch of stuff. But this pattern has worked well for me in the past.

Comment: Oh I see. So essentially I just need to bind my UI to a model object, and then pass that model into my commands class when I bind that?

Comment: Excellent. I did something slightly different (which I'll post in a second) but essentially the same. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

why even implement a command if you are tightly coupling it to UI implementation? Just respond to datagrid.SelectionChanged and code in what supposed to happen.

Otherwise, put it in the ViewModel. Have the ViewModel monitor it's state and evaluate when CanExe is true.

**Edit**

On the other hand, you can pass a parameter to your command, as well as Exe() & CanExe() methods

```
//where T is the type you want to operate on
public static RoutedUICommand<T> OpenDocument { get; set; }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are doing an MVVM solution, this would be the perfect time to implement a publish / subscribe aggregator that allows controls to "talk" to each other.  The gist behind it is that the datagrid would publish an event, 'Open Document'.  Subsequent controls could subscribe to the event and react to the call to 'Open Document'. The publish / subscribe pattern prevents tightly coupling the datagrid and the control.  Do some searches for event aggregators and I think you'll be on your way.